# Подключение классов Laravel

Tags: laravel

Чтобы подключать опрделенные классы для работы в Laravel мне получается нужно помнить наизусть в какой директории лежит определенный класс? Или есть какой то другой способ.Я имею в виду вот это

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Используйте Фасады

2.Используйте любую IDE. Там есть авто заполнение namespace

[image: PHPStorm IDE]

Comment: Спасибо а то работаю в Sublime и убил кучу времени чтобы разобраться какой класс где искать и как подключать!

Comment: Фасады не рекомендованы. [Stop using Facades](http://programmingarehard.com/2014/01/11/stop-using-facades.html/)
Вот почему создатель laravel и отказался использования их в 5 ветке фреймворка.